# Vertical align middle with fullscreen div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Actually I want to make a div full screen and the texts inside the div will be vertically middle. I tried a lot by css but not fully worked as I want. I know if i make the div fixed it will be working but I want to scroll down to the other div also.

I want my project to look like (Initial full screen part): http://perfectpointdev.com/perfect-design/

I want to make the gray background part of my project as the perfectpointdev.com website initial section. Please help me out...

My demo project in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zinannadeem/08wve09t/

```css
#home{
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  min-height:100%;
  vertical-align:milddle;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.welcome-text{
  display:table-cell;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
  z-index:3;
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
  font-size:16px;
  background:#eee;
  z-index:99;
}
.welcome-text .container{
  max-width:800px;margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div class="welcome-text">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>We Are Awesome</h2>
      <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="page-title">Perfect design build awesome templates for you!</h2>
        <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI. Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p>

        <p>Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Buy It Now</a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">See WP Version</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section> 
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="page-title">Perfect design build awesome templates for you!</h2>
        <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI. Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p>

        <p>Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Buy It Now</a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">See WP Version</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section> 
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="page-title">Perfect design build awesome templates for you!</h2>
        <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI. Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p>

        <p>Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Buy It Now</a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">See WP Version</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it would help if you could add a fiddle with the relevant parts of your code

Comment: Might be an idea to use a JavaScript solution. Something like this: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pure css solution :)

HTML

```
<div class="table blue">
<div class="tcell">Middle COntent 1</div>
</div>
<div class="table green">
<div class="tcell">Middle COntent 2</div>
</div>
<div class="table red">
<div class="tcell">Middle COntent 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.table {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
}
.tcell {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
.blue {
background: blue;
}
.red {
background: red;
}
.green {
background: green;
}
```

Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/js4630fd/1/

Comment: do you mean wrong in the context that it doesn't do what it is supposed to do ? or wrong in the sense that it is overly complicated , combursome , outdated, and longer then other solutions?  because I believe it will "work"

Comment: What context are you talking about? It does exactly what it needs, centers the element in the middle, in a page without knowing the height. Far better that the solution with position absolute in a responsive sites, where We need to change the element width and height depending on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -25px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='full-screen'>
  <div class="center">FULL SCREEN</div>
</div>
```

try: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/azuvtgjq/1/)

EDIT: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/pc1zrfn1/1/)

Comment: if i do it then my next section will be hidden . Please visit my jsfiddle and give me suggestion.

Comment: this is pretty much the standard to center something , I wouldn't encourage this type of question though

Comment: @user3535842 - we're not going to do everything for you , instead of making "full-screen" the whole page , make it have a height of like 1400px;

Comment: This is to center something if you have the width or height of the element you want to center.